# Install Angular CLI offline

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

Im a very beginner with Angular and getting into it as part of a project. The version we are using is Angular 4.

They are using Angular CLI. But on the remote PC we are working, there is no internet due to security reason. Node and NPM installed. The packages required for the application is installed using some nupkg files, so internet not required that time. But when we tried to execute the application it only shows a blank page. So I tried this command in powershell and also in PackageManager Console. Im using Visual Studio 2017

> ng --version

It says ng is not recognized. Attaching a screenshot
[image]

But Angular is showing under npm folder of the project.

@angular/cli

Am I missing anything??

Comment: Maybe ng is not configured to be your env variable, try `npm run ng --version`. If it works, then you will have to configure your `enviroment variable`

Comment: Oh.. thats nice.. Now its showing some version as 5.5.1.
So what should I do to configure it

Comment: https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/

Comment: @sforsandeep take a look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183). in this issue there are few solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your package on your computer (direct download), you may use "npm link" in the package folder, this will link the package globally. And you can use "ng" in your bash/shell